# Recurrence relation T(n) = 3T(n-1) + n

Tags: big-o, recurrence

I'm trying to solve the recurrence relation T(n) = 3T(n-1) + n and I think the answer is O(n^3) because each new node spawns three child nodes in the recurrence tree. Is this correct? And, in terms of the recurrence tree, is there a more mathematical way to approach it?

Comment: Not quite `n^3`, but the concept is correct.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be asked on Computer Science SE website.

Answer (score 1):

Recurrence equations are just math: Unfold, sum up and simplify.

```
T(n) = 3T(n-1) + n = 3 (3 T(n - 2) + (n-1)) + n 
     = 3^2 T(n - 3) + 3^2(n-2) + 3(n-1) + n) 
     = ...
     = 3^i T(n - i) + Σ_(j=0..i-1) 3^j * (n-j)
     = Σ_(j=0..n-1) 3^j * (n-j)          // assuming T(0) = 0
```

Now we can find different upper bounds depending on how we much we want to think about it:

```
T(n) = Σ_(j=0..n-1) 3^j * (n-j)
     < n * Σ_(j=0..n-1) 3^j
     = n * (3^n - 1)
```

So `T(n) = O(n*3^n)`.

You can also get a tighter bound by splitting the sum up into two parts:

```
T(n) = Σ_(j=0..n-1) 3^j * (n-j)
     < n * Σ_(j=0..n-x) 3^j * (n-j)     +   x * Σ_(j=n-x..n-1) 3^j
     = n (3^(n-x+1) - 1)  + x * (3^n - 3^(n-x+1))
```

using `x = log_3(n)` you get `T(n) = O(3^n * log(n))`.

You can also approximate the sum `Σ(n-i)3^i` using an integral and get the exact complexity `Θ(3^n)`.